# gesture used on android dial pad

Tags: android, android-emulator, gesture-recognition

I would like to know how can I implement the gesture used on Android phone dial pad?

For example, when I press '1', without lifting up my finger, I drag my finger over to '2', and when I release my finger now, '2' is entered.

I found that most of the library only have `onTouch/onMove` listeners, I have also looked through `GestureDetector`, `motionEvent` but I am unsure which could be used.

May I know which method can I use to achieve this gesture feature?

any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a friend have to do this. He said he had to put a OnTouchListener on the entire layout he wanted to have that functionality, get the raw X and Y, and determine from that and the position of the views within the layout when a certain view was being hovered on.